# WIFI issues with Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b822 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 18.04, realtek

I cannot get WIFI working with Realtek adapter.
 lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:ef100000-ef10ffff

lspci

lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:ef100000-ef10ffff

Comment: Disabling SECURE BOOT - Why I had Microsft's Secure Boot enabled (Ubuntu's Suggestion - Just in the PAST YEAR) is beyonf me